# how to preload audio file using javascript?

Tags: javascript, audio

how to load audio file in a function call without any human interaction. Is this possible only using the javascript? I have tried this code below but it is not working -

```js
const music = new Audio("audiofile.mp3");
function playMusic(){
    music.play();
};
playMusic();
```

Comment: [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting)

Comment: Have you looked into using blobs?

Comment: _"but it is not working"_ - That's not a [valuable error/behavior description](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And what have you tried so far to solve this on your own? And what's the connection to the title (_"how to **preload**..."_)?

Answer (score 0):

### Check the path for the Audio File.

The audio file must be in the main directory. (The directory in which `index.html` is present ).

Check [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/javascript-audio-xu08u?file=/src/index.js) for Working Code.

Comment: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) -> Provide context for links

Comment: thank you for your help, but this is same code that I have tried in my editor, I think browsers doesn't allow automatic music laoding nowadays, we have to put some human interaction such as click, scroll etc I have used a button and it was working fine. If you have any idea apart from this please suggest me.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want audio to play automatically without any user actually playing the audio? if so you can do:

```
 const music = new Audio("audiofile.mp3");
 window.onload = function playMusic(){
 music.play();
  };
```

this will play the audio as soon as the page is loaded, alternatively you can use event listeners to play the audio when certain events happen on the page.

Comment: this code is not working, I have tried in vs code but the result is the same, have you tried in your editor, had the music started playing?